# Using Select Statement from 1 database to insert into another database using VB .NET

Tags: database, vb.net, select, insert

I am currently writing a VB .NET application where I am trying to open 1 database, create a select statement and then post the results into another database file using Microsoft Access database 2003.

The code seems to stop executing at the statement `cmdJetDB.ExecuteNonQuery()`

I am using the following code:

```
Dim conn1 As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data source=C:\Sample.mdb")

Dim conn2 As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data source=C:\db2.mdb")
conn1.Open()
conn2.Open()
Dim mySelectQuery As String 
mySelectQuery = "SELECT Sample.LANE_ADDR, Sample.LANE_DT, Sample.LANE_TM, Sample.LANE_SPEED FROM (Sample) WHERE ((Sample.LANE_ADDR) = '164.909' OR (Sample.LANE_ADDR) = '164.909' AND Sample.LANE_DT BETWEEN #4/4/2003# AND #4/5/2003#)"
Dim cmdJetDB As New OleDbCommand(mySelectQuery, conn1)
cmdJetDB.ExecuteNonQuery()

Dim cmdInsert As String
cmdInsert = "Insert INTO Table1 (Sample.LANE_ADDR, Sample.LANE_TM,Sample.LANE_SPEED) VALUES ('164.909', '00:12:30' , '30' )"
Dim cmdJetDB2 As New OleDbCommand(cmdInsert, conn2)
cmdJetDB2.ExecuteNonQuery()

conn2.Close()
conn1.Close()
```

Question: What is it that I am not doing. I opened both connections, stated my two SQL statements, yet it is still not working. I really need to get this application working. Please Help.........

Answer (score 3):

`ExecuteNonQuery` cannot be used to `SELECT` stuff from a database. You should use `ExecuteReader` and use the result in a loop to **set the parameters** of the `INSERT` statement and then run `ExecuteNonQuery` in that loop. From the code you've written, how you'd expect the values should be populated in the `INSERT` statement?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sugestion,

If the columns you are retriving have the same type as the columns you are inserting (Basicaly you are not making any conversion and/or transformations) do a single query that does this.

```
INSERT INTO TestTable2
SELECT * FROM TestTable1
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You're using `SELECT` to try to return rows, but then calling `ExecuteNonQuery()`, which returns nothing. You'll want to use `ExecuteReader()` instead.
2. You'll probably get another error later because you're `INSERT`ing into "Table1" but trying to reference fields in "Sample".

Also unrelated to the error, but you aren't doing anything with the data in the `SELECT` statement to use it in the `INSERT` statement.